# How to use if loop with for loop in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a passwd file which contains 35000 users and I only need to pull up 205 users. My script is working and giving me details. however, it only giving me 190 users. I assume all other left users do not have any entry in the file.
I want to use an if loop if users exist to put in a found file and if not put in not found file?

```
#!/bin/bash

##/tmp/users.txt is file in which you initialize unix ids

cat /tmp/users.txt | while read line

do

grep -w $line /var/yp/test/passwd | cut -d: -f1,2,3,5 >> /tmp/result.csv

##/tmp/result.csv will store the result

done;
```

Comment: Is this not doing what you want it to do? Is it throwing an error?

Comment: It would be a good idea if you show us format of your passwd file. We maybe able to suggest simpler alternatives.

Comment: I'm afraid you are asking for the impossible. You see, the thing is... there is no `if` *loop*, only `for`, `while`, and `until` loops. Would an `if` *statement* work too? : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```sh
grep -w $line /var/yp/test/passwd | cut -d: -f1,2,3,5 >> /tmp/result.csv
```

to

```sh
    if grep -q -w $line /var/yp/test/passwd ; then
        grep -w $line /var/yp/test/passwd | cut -d: -f1,2,3,5 >> /tmp/result.csv
    else
        echo $line | cut -d: -f1,2,3,5 >> /tmp/not-found.csv
        echo ERROR: Not found: $line
    fi
```

The `-q` makes the first grep not output anything, it just checks if it finds anything and then the result is used by the `if` statement to either execute the normal command or report error.

The "not found" entries will be in `/tmp/not-found.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cat /tmp/users.txt | while read line; do
   if grep -q -w $line /var/yp/test/passwd; then
      echo user $line found 
      grep -w $line /var/yp/test/passwd | cut -d: -f1,2,3,5 >> /tmp/result.csv
   else
      echo user $line not found
   fi
done
##/tmp/result.csv will store the result
```